# changing xcode behavior (move to next word)

Tags: xcode, settings, behavior

I'd like to hit ctrl left or ctrl right to move to last/next word in xcode

Consider a line of code:
[SQLRoutines replaceItem:sender.tag inDictionary:self.objects replaceWith:@"New Header Here" forElement:@"section header"];

You want to quickly move to the middle and change something.  I'd like a keystroke combo that would jump to the next word.

This was common in many other editors I've used, but I can't seem to find it in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: it's under the heading of text and default is alt left and alt right.